# Formatting dashes into number

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, int

I have an id number (idnum)that is equal to 12345678. And is needs to be formatted to look like 123-45-678, which is equal to (new).

```
    newid = (int(idnum[:3]) + "-" + (int(idnum[4:6])) + "-" + (int(idnum[7:9]))
```

That is what I'm typing but its not working. The error I'm getting is "int not subscriptable."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't split an integer into its digits while maintaining it as an integer.

Your best option is to convert your number to a string and then manipulate it accordingly.

i.e.

```
idnum_str = repr(idnum) #number as string
newid = idnum_str[:3] + "-" + idnum_str[4:6] + "-" + idnum_str[7:9]
print(newid)
```